# Access violation while inserting data to std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, std, access-violation, unordered-map

I'm reading read/write configuration for plc from database and storing them in an std::unordered_map.

Whenever, I attempt to insert the extracted record in the std::unordered_map I get an exception. Analyzing variable before insert statement shows data is 
available with the variables.

I am unable to understand why the exception is thrown at 0x00007FFC0C05BD82 (snap7.dll) in SeimensPLC.exe.

Code :

```
//plc_ip         tuple(plc_client_object    read_vector    write_vector)
std::unordered_map<std::string, plc_common::plc_config_data_tuple> plc_;

std::optional<TS7Client> plc::connect_plc(const std::string& ip, std::uint8_t connectionType, std::uint16_t rack, std::uint16_t slot)
{
    TS7Client client;
    client.SetConnectionType(connectionType);   //PG-PC : Programming Console type connection
    if (client.ConnectTo(ip.c_str(), rack, slot) not_eq EXIT_SUCCESS)
        return std::nullopt;
    return client;
}

bool plc::add_plc(const std::string& ip, const std::vector<config_table_struct>& config_list)
{
    try
    {
        std::optional<TS7Client> client = this->connect_plc(ip);
        if (not client.has_value())
        {
            std::string strErr = fmt::format("Unable to connect to plc : {}", ip);          
            LOG_ERROR << strErr;
            return false;
        }
        plc_common::read_vector         read_vector;
        plc_common::write_vector        write_vector;
        std::for_each(config_list.begin(), config_list.end(), [&](const config_table_struct& config_struct) {

            plc_common::config_struct   config;
            config.serial_no        = config_struct.serial_no;
            config.area_number      = config_struct.area_number;
            config.read_location    = config_struct.read_location;
            config.read_length      = config_struct.read_length;
            config.scan_rate        = config_struct.scan_rate;
            config.data_type        = config_struct.data_type;
            config.area_type        = 0x84;
            config.data_queue       = plc_common::data_queue{};
            read_vector.push_back(config);
        });
        plc_common::plc_config_data_tuple plc_config_data_tuple = std::make_tuple(client.value(), read_vector, write_vector);
        this->plc_.insert(std::make_pair(ip, plc_config_data_tuple)); //Executing this statement gives exception
        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {       
        LOG_FATAL << "Exception : " << ex.what();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Exception :

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC0C05BD82 (snap7.dll) in SeimensPLC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF04.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC0C05BD82 (snap7.dll) in SeimensPLC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF04.
```

---

Edit :

As requested I have added all typedefs.

```
typedef std::variant<bool, std::uint8_t, std::int16_t, std::int32_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t, std::float_t, char> plc_data_type;
typedef std::queue<plc_common::plc_data_type>                       data_queue;
typedef struct {
    std::uint32_t           serial_no;
    std::uint8_t            area_type;
    std::uint8_t            area_number;
    std::uint16_t           read_location;
    std::uint16_t           read_length;
    std::string             data_type;
    std::uint32_t           scan_rate;
    plc_common::data_queue  data_queue;
} config_struct;
//read_vector/write_vector      area_type    area_number    read/write_location   read/write_size     scanRate     read/write_queue   
typedef std::vector<plc_common::config_struct> read_vector, write_vector;
//                   s7_socket    vector storing read/write information
typedef std::tuple<TS7Client, plc_common::read_vector, plc_common::write_vector> plc_config_data_tuple;
```

Comment: It's possible that `*this` is not an object that exists.

Comment: You didn't mix debug and release DLLs or DLLs compiled with distinct versions of VC++?

Comment: Aside: please don't do this: `if (not client.has_value())`, always write `if (!client.has_value())`

Comment: This error means that you are trying to access a location/memory which not declared/set yet. I got the same error some days ago and solved by checking undeclared memory.

Comment: It looks like you are calling methods on an object (either `this` or `plc_`) that either never existed (uninitialized) or has seized to exist (already destroyed). The first would be, well, uninitialized memory. The second one likely comes from a dangling pointer/reference. But without a [mcve] we cannot help you much further.

Comment: @Scheff, I rechecked the DLLs. I have not mixed debug and release DLLs. I know abut the typographical error `SeimensPLC.exe`. I'm going to rectify it once project is done. I used the same DLL (Debug) in another project the it worked.

Comment: I executed the following code to check if `plc_` std::unordered_map exist and I'm getting the output.

`spdlog::critical("Max Bucket Count : {}",  this->plc_.max_bucket_count());
spdlog::critical("Max Load Factor : {}",  this->plc_.max_load_factor());
spdlog::critical("Max Size : {}",  this->plc_.max_size());`

Output :

`[2019-05-23 16:19:54.682] [critical] Max Bucket Count : 1152921504606846975
[2019-05-23 16:19:54.683] [critical] Max Load Factor : 1
[2019-05-23 16:19:54.683] [critical] Max Size : 144115188075855871`

Comment: @DarkSorrow There is no way to check whether something is a valid object.

Comment: @molbdnilo, should I explicitly call the constructor to make sure that object is created.

Comment: @DarkSorrow How are you creating the object in question? (There is no way to explicitly call a constructor. It's not a function, and it doesn't have a name.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, I have not explicitly called the constructor for `plc_` object. I am using the empty container constructor (default constructor) as mentioed in the first line `std::unordered_map<std::string, plc_common::plc_config_data_tuple> plc_;`

Comment: @DarkSorrow And the object that has `plc_` as a member  - the `plc` instance - how are you creating that?

Comment: @Scheff, As requested I have edited my original post to include all typedefs.

Comment: @molbdnilo, In main.cpp I created the plc object using `plc plc`; and called the add_plc method using `plc.add_plc(plc_ip, config_list.value())`. The config list is filled by reading the database using `std::optional<std::vector<config_table_struct>> config_list = db.get_config(plc_ip);`

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to understand why the exception is thrown at
>   0x00007FFC0C05BD82

You should be aware that this is not C++ exception is thrown, but [access violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is raised by hardware with memory protection. There could be a lot of reasons of this. One of the most often reason is invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere in the code with subsequent memory corruption or access of the memory which should not normally be accessed.

As for how to debug, you can use [Dr. Memory](https://drmemory.org/) on Windows or Valgrind, if you were on Linux.